# how to keep the selected items selected even if data is re loaded?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am working on a project where I have to select multiple items from a recyclerview and store it in arrayList/ But my data is changed with spinner. I want my data to stay selected even if i change spinner vaue and come back. And in this anyways my selection and deselction is working little weird. I am attaching a video here, [sample video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zf1T50pRuAmtmH5qFxEKTPhIq4KCMJJj/view?usp=sharing). Please suggest me the changes i need to do to make it work fine.

My recyclerview adapter class below

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(val dataList:ArrayList<ModelClass>,val onItemClicked: (Int) -> Unit):RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

   object ob {
        val dataSelected= ArrayList<ModelClass>()

   }


    private var checkedPosition = -1


    fun setData(listModel: List<ModelClass>) {
        dataList.clear()
        dataList.addAll(listModel)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }




    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemViewBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
        )
        return ViewHolder(binding, parent.context)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(dataList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataList.size

    inner class ViewHolder(
        val binding: ItemViewBinding,
        val context: Context
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor", "ResourceType")
        fun bindItems(data: ModelClass) = with(binding) {
            binding.itemQuant.text=data.item_quant
            binding.itemName.text=data.item_name
            binding.mfgName.text=data.mfg
            binding.quantity.text=data.item_stock.toString()

            when (checkedPosition) {
                -1 -> {
                    itemView.setBackgroundResource(0)
                }
                else -> when (checkedPosition) {
                    adapterPosition -> {
                        itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black)

                    }
                    else -> {
                        itemView.setBackgroundResource(0)
                    }
                }
            }
            root.setOnClickListener {
             // itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black)
                if (checkedPosition != adapterPosition) {
                    notifyItemChanged(checkedPosition)
                    checkedPosition = adapterPosition
                }

                // Handle the clicked item

                if (ob.dataSelected.contains(dataList[adapterPosition])){
                    checkedPosition=0
                    ob.dataSelected.remove(dataList[adapterPosition])
                    itemView.isSelected=false
                    for (i in ob.dataSelected){
                        println(i.sku_code)
                    }
                    itemView.setBackgroundResource(0)

                }
                else {
                    checkedPosition=1
                    ob.dataSelected.add(dataList[adapterPosition])
                    itemView.isSelected=true
                    for (i in ob.dataSelected){
                        println(i.sku_code)
                    }
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black)

                }
                onItemClicked.invoke(checkedPosition)
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

edit:

```
 class RecyclerViewAdapter(val dataList:ArrayList<ModelClass>,val onItemClicked: (Int) -> Unit):RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

 object ob {
     val dataSelected = ArrayList<ModelClass>()

 }


 fun setData(listModel: List<ModelClass>) {
     dataList.clear()
     dataList.addAll(listModel)
     notifyDataSetChanged()
 }


 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
     val binding = ItemViewBinding.inflate(
         LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
     )
     return ViewHolder(binding, parent.context)
 }


 @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

     holder.bindItems(dataList[position])

 }

 override fun getItemCount() = dataList.size

 inner class ViewHolder(
     val binding: ItemViewBinding,
     val context: Context
 ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
     @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
     fun restore(){


         for (i in 0 until ob.dataSelected.size){
             for (j in 0 until dataList.size){
                 if (ob.dataSelected[i].sku_code==(dataList[j]).sku_code) {
                     if(adapterPosition == j){

                         itemView.isSelected = true
                         itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black)
                         println("****")

                     }
                 }

             }}}

     @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor", "ResourceType")
     fun bindItems(data: ModelClass) = with(binding) {

         binding.itemQuant.text = data.item_quant
         binding.itemName.text = data.item_name
         binding.mfgName.text = data.mfg
         binding.quantity.text = data.item_stock.toString()

         restore()


             itemView.setOnClickListener {
                 var isPresent = false
                 for (item in ob.dataSelected) {
                     if (item == data) {
                         isPresent = true
                     }
                 }

                 if (isPresent) {
                     it.setBackgroundResource(0)
                     ob.dataSelected.remove(dataList[adapterPosition])
                     for (i in ob.dataSelected) {
                         println(i.sku_code)
                     }
                 } else {
                     it.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black)

                     ob.dataSelected.add(dataList[adapterPosition])
                     for (i in ob.dataSelected) {
                         println(i.sku_code)
                     }
                 }
                onItemClicked.invoke(adapterPosition)
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

i have coded for you and share whit you my project code here.

**the key point for solving your problem:**

your items in recyclerview should contain an unique id, whit that id you able to check existance of an item in checked-Arraylist-Items
if you use Api for recyceerview data and those api have not id, then you should add your id to your data model before showing in list

here are my project files, i hope work for you!

**activity_spinner.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SpinnerActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rc_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**rc_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**SpinnerConst.kt:**

```
object SpinnerConst {
var checkedItems = ArrayList<Int>()
```

}

**ListAdapter.kt:**

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ListAdapter( var mList: List<MyDataModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.rc_item, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val rcItem = mList[position]

        holder.textView.text = rcItem.name

        if(SpinnerConst.checkedItems.contains(rcItem.id)){
            holder.container.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"))
        }else{
            holder.container.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
        }





        holder.container.setOnClickListener {
            var isPresent = false
            for (item in SpinnerConst.checkedItems) {
                if (item == rcItem.id) {
                    isPresent = true
                }
            }

            if (isPresent) {
                it.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                SpinnerConst.checkedItems.remove(rcItem.id)
            } else {
                it.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"))
                SpinnerConst.checkedItems.add(rcItem.id)
            }


        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
        val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name)
        val container: ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_container)
    }

    fun updateList(newlist:List<MyDataModel>){
        this.mList = newlist
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

**MyDataModel.kt:**

```
data class MyDataModel(var id: Int, var name: String)
```

**SpinnerActivity.kt**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class SpinnerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var dataList = ArrayList<MyDataModel>()
    lateinit var spinner: Spinner
    lateinit var rc_spinner: RecyclerView
    var spinnerArray = arrayOf("All", "Bingo", "Kurkure", "Cheetos")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner)
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        rc_spinner = findViewById(R.id.rc_spinner)


        ///////////////////////create sample data ////////////////////////////

        dataList.add( MyDataModel(1, "Cheetos"))
        dataList.add(MyDataModel(2, "Cheetos"))

        dataList.add( MyDataModel(3, "Bingo"))
        dataList.add(MyDataModel(4, "Bingo"))

        dataList.add( MyDataModel(5, "Kurkure"))
        dataList.add(MyDataModel(6, "Kurkure"))

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////

        var adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray)
        spinner.adapter = adapter


        var rc_adapter = ListAdapter(dataList)
        rc_spinner.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rc_spinner.adapter = rc_adapter


        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object :
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    when(position){
                        0-> rc_adapter.updateList(dataList)
                        1-> rc_adapter.updateList(filterByName(spinnerArray.get(position)))
                        2-> rc_adapter.updateList(filterByName(spinnerArray.get(position)))
                        3-> rc_adapter.updateList(filterByName(spinnerArray.get(position)))
                    }

            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                // write code to perform some action
            }
        }
    }



    fun filterByName(filterName:String):ArrayList<MyDataModel>{
        var filterdList = ArrayList<MyDataModel>()
        for(item in dataList){
            if(item.name == filterName){
                filterdList.add(item)
            }

        }

        return filterdList
    }


}
```

Comment: Hey soheil, i took your advice and edited my code, i have added it under edit in my question, but selection is still not working fine. if i select item in one screen and change spinner value , a random object is already selected there. Is there anything i can do about it?

Comment: did you run my codes? everything whit those code files is ok! i tested again whit emulator and real device and was ok again! run my code and read codes line by line